# Activity recognition API not detecting location changes - Android OREO

Tags: java, android, intentservice, android-8.0-oreo, activity-recognition

Issue : Activity recognition API has an intent service which will get the motion activities and will get as part of intent (onHandleIntent). When I changed my app to target android Oreo, the functionality behaves as below

1. While app is in foreground, app detects activities.
2. while app in background, it doesn't detect activities

I tried to change the intent service to JobIntentService but not working.

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: @deniz Did you find a solution excepts using foreground service?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. My app worked like charm on previous versions of Android, but no location updates in Oreo.

Found the solution in:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits.html

I have a service as location listener that runs in the background. In orea background services get only few location updates. It has to be changed to a foreground service.
The only thing I had to do is calling startForeground() within onCreate() of the service.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for [location retreiving limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html) for apps on Oreo when in background or using background services. The answer is to use foreground service or bring app to foreground.